# Getting row value from DB by matching two column using Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table like below structure.

table name `users`

```
id  Receipt_No   type   v_amount    v_date      c_date      v_name    v_status

7    150325006   SWD     60.00     2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No

8    150325006   GOODS   1195.00   2015-04-15  2015-04-28   Deepak    No

9    150325006   BURNING  290.00   2015-04-15  2015-04-28  Deep       No

10   150325006   BURNING  290.00   2015-04-15   2015-04-15  Deep      No
```

I know only v_catagory and v_name column value.Suppose i have `v_catagory="Deep" and v_name="BURNING"` information.I need all row value whose `v_name ="Deep" and v_catagory="BURNING"` and finally display all required value in a table that means `id no-9.10` should display in a table.Please help me.

Comment: No. 8 is neither deep nor burning.

Comment: @ Santosh : Ohh sorry its 9 and 10.

Comment: Are `type` and `v_catagory` the same things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `where` method (assuming your model is `User`).

in your `*_controller.rb`:

```
@result = User.where(type: 'BURNING', v_name: 'Deep')
```

in your view:

```
<table>
  <% @result.each do |r| %>
     <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag :check_value, 1, :id => "checkbox1-1" %></th>
        <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Raw sql:

```
select * 
from users
where type = 'BURNING' and v_name = 'Deep'
```

Comment: @ notulysses : I got success to assign all row values to a variable but one problem is there it is throwing error when trying to display all column value in table.

Comment: @satya: You can just assign `User.where(type: 'BURNING', v_name: 'Deep')` to a local variable, like `@user` and then iterate through it with `each` to build a table.

Comment: No check what i did ,

result << PaymentVendor.where(:Receipt_No => params[:Receipt_No],:v_catagory =>  params[:payment][:s_catagory],:v_name => params[:v_name] )

Comment: Just assign to a local variable instead of pushing in array.

Comment: @ notulysses : Then i did inside the table like this.
 <% result.each do |r| %>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag :check_value, 1, :id => "checkbox1-1"  %></th>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>

Comment: @ notulysses : Why i am pushing to array i may fetch multiple rows in future.

Comment: @satya: it already fetches records as an array of instances and you are pushing this array in another array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76599/discussion-between-satya-and-notulysses).

Comment: @satya: You can use snippet from the answer, I've updated it.